# c++ function definition is not allowed here

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

This is for my c++ class, which is taught on windows while I use xcode on mac. the problem states: 
 Write a program that uses a function displayMenu to display the following  menu:

Math Program:
 1. Add two numbers
 2. Subtract two numbers
 3. Multiply two numbers
 4. Divide two numbers
 5. Quit

and basically I'm supposed to use switch statements/cases to make the program run. I keep getting "function definition is not allowed here" and I'm stuck on how to get the program to run. If anyone could help me find my mistakes or where I'm going wrong that would be a life saver!

and here is the code I have written:

```
    #include <iostream>

    float addNumbers(float, float);
    float subtractNumbers(float, float);
    float multiplyNumbers(float, float);
    float divideNumbers(float, float);
    float Result;
    void displayMenu();

    int main(void)
    {
    {

int choice;
float Number1, Number2, Result, quit;

displayMenu();
std::cin >> choice;
do
{
    if (choice > 0 && choice < 5)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter two numbers: ";
        std::cin >> Number1 >> Number2;
    }
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Result = addNumbers(Number1, Number2);
            std::cout << "The numbers added are " << Result << std::endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            Result = subtractNumbers(Number1, Number2);
            std::cout << "The numbers subtracted are " << Result << std::endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            Result = multiplyNumbers(Number1, Number2);
            std::cout << "The numbers multiplied are " << Result <<                              std::endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            Result = divideNumbers(Number1, Number2);
            std::cout << "The numbers divided are " << Result << std::endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            Result = quit;

        default:
            break;

    }

    displayMenu();
    std::cin >> choice;

} while (choice != 5);
    }

    void displayMenu()
    {
        std::cout << "Math Program\n";
        std::cout << "1. Add two numbers\n";
        std::cout << "2. Subtract two numbers\n";
        std::cout << "3. Multiply two numbers\n";
        std::cout << "4. Divide two numbers\n";
        std::cout << "5. quit\n";
    }

    float AddNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
    {
       Result = (Number1 + Number2);
    }

    float SubtractNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
    {
         Result = (Number1 - Number2);
    }

    float MultiplyNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
    {
         Result = (Number1 * Number2);
    }

    float DivideNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
    {
        Result = (Number1 / Number2);
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting in first place please! It should become clearer where the problem lies then. You cannot define a function within the body of another function (unless you're using lambda expressions).

Comment: You can't define functions inside functions. You need to end one before you start the next.

Comment: `Result = (Number1 + Number2);` C++ isn't Delphi!! Use `return (Number1 + Number2);` instead (equivalent to `exit(Number1 + Number2);` in Delphi code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems with your code. Make sure to place your functions outside your `main()` also make sure your functions are returning values. If you declare a function as `float getSum()` it should return a float value. Those were the obvious errors. Minor errors include you forgetting to keep the name exactly the same for the functions. One part you started with lower case and next you gave them capital.

Here I fixed up the code for you.

```
#include <iostream>

float addNumbers(float, float);
float subtractNumbers(float, float);
float multiplyNumbers(float, float);
float divideNumbers(float, float);
float Result;
void displayMenu();

int main(void)
{
    {

        int choice;
        float Number1, Number2, Result, quit;

        displayMenu();
        std::cin >> choice;
        do
        {
            if (choice > 0 && choice < 5)
            {
                std::cout << std::endl << "Enter two numbers: ";
                std::cin >> Number1 >> Number2;
            }
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                Result = addNumbers(Number1, Number2);
                std::cout << "The numbers added are " << Result << std::endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                Result = subtractNumbers(Number1, Number2);
                std::cout << "The numbers subtracted are " << Result << std::endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                Result = multiplyNumbers(Number1, Number2);
                std::cout << "The numbers multiplied are " << Result << std::endl;
                break;

            case 4:
                Result = divideNumbers(Number1, Number2);
                std::cout << "The numbers divided are " << Result << std::endl;
                break;

            case 5:
                Result = quit;

            default:
                break;

            }

            displayMenu();
            std::cin >> choice;

        } while (choice != 5);
    }

    return 0;
}

void displayMenu()
{
    std::cout << "Math Program\n";
    std::cout << "1. Add two numbers\n";
    std::cout << "2. Subtract two numbers\n";
    std::cout << "3. Multiply two numbers\n";
    std::cout << "4. Divide two numbers\n";
    std::cout << "5. quit\n";
}

float addNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
{
    return (Number1 + Number2);
}

float subtractNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
{
    return (Number1 - Number2);
}

float multiplyNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
{
    return (Number1 * Number2);
}

float divideNumbers(float Number1, float Number2)
{
    return (Number1 / Number2);
}
```

Comment: Why the definitions appearing after the forward declarations? That doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: you define your function outside main if you already have forward declarations made for them. You could define the functions after the main also. But as long as they are outside the main - remeber you are calling for them from "inside" the main function - you should be fine. Try the code i made for you i think it will work. you might have tweek a bit but important stuff are there.

Comment: _"Try the code i made for you i think it will work. "_ Sure that code will work. But if you define all of these functions before the `main()` function, the forward declarations are redundant. That's what I meant.

Comment: oh oops ya you are right. i thought i put them after main. sorry about that

Comment: I fixed that for you now. And have a +1 for fixing that silly Delphi like confusion about the `return` statements.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this was a last resort for me. I understand that this was a poor question, so I will be more diligent when asking in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `displayMenu()` and all ones following it are defined within `main()`.

This is exactly what compiler says. Move them all out of `main()` and you're fine.

Comment: OP already has _forward declarations_.

Comment: yes, didn't notice them firstly.